# Change values of second part of bar chart in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

df

```
  channel    ratio_customer_to_lead_owner      ratio_customer_to_agent
0 Facebook             2                                  5
1 Bing                 1                                  1
2 Google               6                                 13
```

The code below returns two bar graphs with the same results.
How can I change the second part of the bar graph so that its values come from another column called 'ratio_customer_to_agent'?

```
# create plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
n_groups = 3
index = np.arange(n_groups)
bar_width = 0.35
opacity = 0.8

X = np.arange(2)
plt.bar(X + 0.00, channel_ratios['ratio_customer_to_lead_owner'][0], color = 'b', width = 0.25,
       label='Facebook')
plt.bar(X + 0.25, channel_ratios['ratio_customer_to_lead_owner'][1], color = 'g', width = 0.25,
       label='Bing')
plt.bar(X + 0.50, channel_ratios['ratio_customer_to_lead_owner'][2], color = 'r', width = 0.25,
       label='Google')

plt.ylabel('Ratio')
plt.title('Ratio of Customer to Lead Owner & Customer to Sales Agent')
plt.xticks(index + bar_width, ('Customer/Lead Owner', 'Customer/Sales Agent'))
plt.legend()

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Result: 
[image]

Expected result:
The second blue bar shows the value of 5, the second green bar 1, the second red bar 13.

Comment: `df.set_index('channel').T.plot(kind = 'bar')` ??

Comment: but how do I combine it with the initial code  (or change the code altogether)?

Comment: i have 2 series I want to plot in the same graph

Comment: the above line will plot the 2 series in the same graph. I've added the complete example in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'channel': {0: 'Facebook', 1: 'Bing', 2: 'Google'},
                   'ratio_customer_to_lead_owner': {0: 2, 1: 1, 2: 6},
                   'ratio_customer_to_agent': {0: 5, 1: 1, 2: 13}})

df.set_index('channel').T.plot(kind='bar')
```

OUTPUT:

[image]